# How set up read/write capacity in dynamodb with ServiceStack.Aws

Tags: c#, servicestack, amazon-dynamodb, pocodynamo

I want to set up a custom read/write capacity when SeriviceStack.Aws synchronizes my model.

I have this model

```
[Alias("TABLE-NAME")]
public class Company
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

And is created with this code

```
var awsDb = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
            var db = new PocoDynamo(awsDb)
                .RegisterTable<Company>();

            db.InitSchema();
```

How can set up a custom read/write capacity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ProvisionedThroughput](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/TDynamoDBv2ProvisionedThroughput.html) capacities can be set through a [ProvisionedThroughputAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/45c6f47caed7690da620b1f5f1bdc499217da3e4/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/DynamoCodes.cs#L142) on a table POCO or defaults can be controlled on the `PocoDynamo` client by the `ReadCapacityUnits` and `WriteCapacityUnits` properties.

Tables are created by the `InitSchema` call which check if the registered table type has the [ProvisionedThroughputAttribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/2db733334899bb984e00a7a142743639d93c54cd/tests/ServiceStack.Aws.DynamoDbTests/Shared/DataModels.cs#L665) first and [falling back to the client specified capacities](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Aws/DynamoDb/PocoDynamo.cs#L204) which by default are set to 10 Read, 5 Write.